# What is the general method I can use to make my UV islands not be entangled?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm currently working on an anvil following Blender Guru's anvil tutorial. I'm at the unwrapping UVs part (https://youtu.be/scPSP_U858k?t=807), but for some reason when I select one part of my island, it instaselects another island that should not be "entangled" together. I think it's because of the seams, so I tried changing them a bit which made the unwrap look crazy. What method can I use to fix it? I'm guessing this will depend on my specific mesh so here's the blend file https://pasteall.org/media/c/9/c96420b7be91f3cd54f57af9ac4cca86.blend

[image]com/UtVtQ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have select sync turned on.
[image: select sync]
Nothing is wrong here. The mesh components are touching in 3D, and since that option is on, blender shows the whole UV map. Any pseudo-duplicate vertices that are on the border of two patches and thus part of both get selected as one.

Turn off select sync to avoid undesired effects from this.